# Failed Android 7.1.2 install on LG V500 - stuck on boot screen

Tags: lg, 7.1-nougat

I had CWM Recovery and an older cyanogenmod rom installed on my LG G Pag 8.3 (V500) and I wanted to upgrade to 7.1.2 from here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-...8-r16-t3476750

I copied the ROM to internal memory, rebooted into recovery, selected the rom file to install. It showed some messages about patching, then in a couple of minuted erred with smth like "Erro loki-ifying because of incompatible aboot image".

I then rebooted and now it boots and shows "ANDROID" and is stuck on it - looks like it partially updated the ROM and failed somewhere.

I am not sure what to do now - I tried to boot into recovery (Power off -> Hold Power + Vol down till menu shows) but it doesnt work - it keeps booting onto this stuck boot.

Is there a way to fix it or have I just finally bricked it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by downloading LG Mobile Support Tool, switching the tableto into download mode (Power Off, then press both Up and Down vlume until it shows download mode), then connecting the USB and after the LG Mobile Support tool recognizes the tablet, go to Options -> Upgrade Recovery.
The tool will download and flash the latest stock image. 
After that I got stuck on boot loop and performed factory reset:

- Press and hold Power Button + Volume Down
- When the LG logo shows up, release the power button only
- Now press and hold the Power and Volume Up button while keeping your hold on the Volume Down button
- When the factory reset screen appears, release your hold on all buttons
- Follow On Screen Indications

Now I get a fully stock tablet that I can root, install custom recovery etc

Comment: As side note, I was never able to successfully flash the "pure" ROM from that xda-developer page I posted in the question. I ended up flashing the latest LineageOS and the tablet works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

The answer you posted only got your tablet to working state, but LOS still isn't installed.

To actually install LOS, first make sure your stock OS is at least Android 4.4, then install [TWRP recovery](https://twrp.me/devices/lggpad83.html) (since CWM is long dead) according to the instruction on the page (`fastboot` installation is heavily recommended), and finally flash [LOS](https://download.lineageos.org/v500) itself.

Comment: Note: I've sold my V500 for a while now, so there might be missing steps - feel free to point out.

Comment: Off-topic: Let me recommend [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116). It's a good small plugin that allows you to insert comment from templates. Very helpful in reviews.

Comment: @iBug You used this to auto-insert the "site rules" comments I saw you posted? Nice touch.

Comment: Yes. **Exactly!** (I will delete these OT comments tomorrow).

Comment: Indeed, this was recommended to me by people on MSE. A few 10kers and mods are using it.

Comment: @AndyYan - my question was really about getting my table unbricked, not how to install a custom OS. And that is what I finally figured out and posted as an answer. Installing custom recovery and a custom ROM was out of scope of the question

Comment: Well you said you were attempting to install LOS, so I thought you were still interested in figuring it out.